# Merge/combine overlapping timeranges in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an table with several contract-informations to each customer and its locations.

Each customer can have 1-x locations at the same time. each location can have x contracts, but not overlapping.

Now I need to cluster this informations to overall-timeranges

Example as image:

[uploaded to imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAnsQ.png)

As table:

sourcetable:

| Customer-Id | location-id | contract_signed | contract_start | contract_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 001 | '2012-04-02' | '2012-09-01' | '2014-04-15' |
| 123 | 001 | '2014-12-01' | '2015-01-01' | '2018-03-31' |
| 123 | 001 | '2019-07-01' | '2020-01-01' | '2021-09-30' |
| 123 | 002 | '2012-07-01' | '2012-09-01' | '2014-04-15' |
| 123 | 002 | '2014-12-01' | '2015-07-01' | '2018-03-31' |
| 123 | 002 | '2018-07-01' | '2018-10-01' | '2021-09-30' |
| 123 | 003 | '2014-09-01' | '2015-07-01' | '2018-03-31' |

and the result that i want:

| Customer-Id | contract_signed | contract_start | contract_end | days_without_contract |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | '2012-04-02' | '2012-09-01' | '2014-04-15' | NULL |
| 123 | '2014-09-01' | '2015-01-01' | '2018-03-31' | 139 |
| 123 | '2018-07-01' | '2018-07-01' | '2021-09-30' | 92 |

Answer (score 1):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  You can use a cumulative `max()` to determine if there is no overlap.  If there is none, then that is the start of an "island" and aggregation does the rest of the work:

```
select customer_id, min(contract_signed),
       min(contract_start), max(contract_end),
       datediff(day, max(contract_end), lag(contract_start) over (order by customer_id)) as days_without_contract
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_contract_end >= contract_start then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by customer_id order by contract_start) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   max(contract_end) over (partition by customer_id 
                                           order by contract_start, location
                                           rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                                          ) as prev_contract_end
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
group by customer_id, grp;
```

Comment: heyho, ty for reply. "rows between unbounded preceding and 1 row" wont work in sqlserver. with "rows between unbounded preceding AND CURRENT ROW" i'll get negative datediffs and too much rows...

Comment: @oShortyo . . . That should be `1 preceding`.